# I can't use the window manager of my choice, nor the display manager

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, xorg, window-manager

I'm stuck with xfce and a text-only login screen. I've tried to run

```
startkde
```

instead of

```
startx
```

to see GUI and I got this

```
$DISPLAY is not set or cannot connect to the X server.
```

I tried to fix it many ways but I think I'm kinda dumb so I need your help.

Comment: Answered here: [xorg - Can't run KDE on Arch, $DISPLAY not set - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/445057/cant-run-kde-on-arch-display-not-set)